# Shortcut to Compare to Latest Version in Solution Explorer - Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

In Visual Studio 2012, in the Solution Explorer (*not* Pending Changes), is there any way to create a keyboard shortcut, right click context menu item, or menu bar button that does a TFS Compare to Latest Version?

Alternatively, on the general Compare dialog, is there any way to change the default selection of Type: Workspace Version to Type: Latest Version?

Basically I am looking for the easiest way to get to Compare to Latest using the fewest clicks, from the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 6):

Does setting a `Tools/Options/Keyboard` shortcut for `TfsCompare` help?

[image]

Comment: What I really want is just to jump to the Compare to Latest Version.  The TfsCompare would be more useful if the default selection of Workspace Version could be changed to Latest Version.

Comment: @Rob G - did you find a solution to that?

Answer (score 3):

For me, this worked:

```
VS > Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Show Commands Containing: Team.Git.CompareWithUnmodified
```

By assigning a shortcut key `Ctrl+\, Ctrl+\` to this command ( *Team.Git.CompareWithUnmodified*) I can now compare my current file (the file that is open in the editor) to the previous version of the file by pressing the shortcut key `Ctrl+\, Ctrl+\`; no need to find the file in solution explorer, then right-click the file then select Compare.

(you can choose your own shortcut key of course)

*Just a note on different behaviour:*

- `Team.Git.CompareWithUnmodified` works for me because I am using TeamExplorer in VisualStudio but I use GIT as the underlying source code repository.
- `Tfs.FileCompare` could also work in other scenarios (i.e. if you don't use Git, but use VSTS or TFS as your source control provider).

Comment: Yes!  I mapped this in VS2019 to ALT+SHIFT+G (don't need SQL.SSDTSchemaCompareGenerateScript as a hotkey . . .)